# How to increment JavaScript variables with onclick and wrap around JavaScript arrays?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, increment

I am trying to write a webpage that takes input with an HTML form and produces output through textboxes. The output and input are stored in a two dimensional 10x6 array.

The webpage allows you to create a new sale/ form which is stored in the next array row, view the previous sale/form (which wraps around if you are at the first sale), and view the next sale/form (which wraps around if you are at the last sale/form).

My problem is that I don't know how to increment two variables that control where in the array the information is stored, and how I can view the previous/next sales which also wrap around.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
"use strict"; // Use JavaScript in strict mode

    // This function will reset all form values except
    // for the Sale ID and sale count
    function clearForm(){
        document.getElementById('coffeeType').value = " ";
        document.getElementById('coffeeSize').value = " ";
        document.getElementById("subtotal").value = " ";
        document.getElementById("salesTax").value = " ";
        document.getElementById("total").value = " ";
    }

    // This function will execute when the user clicks the "New Sale"
    // button, which will automatically clear the form and change the
    // Sale ID and Sales Count values.
    function newSale() {
        // The sale count will depend on the length of the array
        // Ex: if there are 2 rows ([0] and [1]), the length = 2, thus saleNum = 2
        saleNum = salesInfo.length ;
        // Reseting the form so the user can eneter new information
        document.getElementById("coffeeForm").reset();
        document.getElementById("saleID").value = 1000 + saleNum;
        document.getElementById("salesCount").value = saleNum;
        // Output the salesInfo array into the developer log
        console.log(salesInfo);
    }

    // This function will be used in the previousSale() and nextSale()
    // functions to output the previous or next sale into the HTML form
    function getSale(saleNumber) {
        document.getElementById('coffeeType').value = salesInfo[saleNum].coffeeType;
        document.getElementById('coffeeSize').value = salesInfo[saleNum].coffeeSize;
        document.getElementById("saleID").value = salesInfo[saleNum].saleID;
        document.getElementById("subtotal").value = salesInfo[saleNum].subtotal.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("salesTax").value = salesInfo[saleNum].salesTax.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("total").value = salesInfo[saleNum].total.toFixed(2);
    }

    // This function will show the previous sale when the user clicks
    // a button by decrementing/incrementing array values
    function previousSale() {
        // If the saleNum (salesInfo[index]) value is greater than zero, it will decrement
        if (saleNum > 0) {
            saleNum--;
        }
        // If the saleNum is at the oldest sale, it will show the newest sale
        else if (saleNum == 0 && salesInfo.length > 1){
            // Do something?
        }
        getSale(saleNum);
    }

    // This function will show the next sale when the user clicks
    // a button by decrementing/incrementing array values
    function nextSale() {
        // If the saleNum (salesInfo[index]) value is greater than the array length, it will increment
        if (saleNum < salesInfo.length - 1) {
            saleNum++;
        }
        // If the saleNum is at the newest sale, it will show the oldest sale
        else if (saleNum == salesInfo.length - 1){
            // Do something?
        }
        getSale(saleNum);
    }

    // This function will verify user input and genereate errors if it is not accepted,
    // otherwise is will store information in an array and perform calculations,
    // and return output using an HTML form
    function confirmForm() {
        var coffeeType = document.getElementById('coffeeType').value.toUpperCase(),
            coffeeSize = document.getElementById('coffeeSize').value.toUpperCase(),
            saleID = document.getElementById('saleID').value;

        // If the coffee type is not found in the price object ('L', 'B', or 'D'),
        // generate an error and return false.
        if (!price[coffeeType]) {
            alert("Error: Please enter a valid coffee type (L - Light, B - Blend, D - Dark)!");
            return false;
        }

        // If the coffee size is not found in the price object ('S', 'M', or 'L'),
        // generate an error and return false.
        if (!price[coffeeType][coffeeSize]) {
            alert("Error: Please enter a valid coffee size (S - Small, M - Medium, L - Large).");
            return false;
        }

        // Subtotal will vary depending on coffee type and coffee size, which uses an object
        var subtotal = price[coffeeType][coffeeSize];
        /* ****** Calculating the sales tax and total ****** */
        var salesTax = subtotal * 0.06;
        var total = subtotal + salesTax;
        /* ************************************************* */

        // Assigns salesInfo[saleNum] to salesInfo[saleNum] if it exists, or an empty object if it doesnt
        salesInfo[saleNum] = salesInfo[saleNum] || {};

        salesInfo[saleNum].saleID = saleID;
        salesInfo[saleNum].coffeeType = coffeeType;
        salesInfo[saleNum].coffeeSize = coffeeSize;
        salesInfo[saleNum].subtotal = subtotal;
        salesInfo[saleNum].salesTax = salesTax;
        salesInfo[saleNum].total = total;
        // Return the output to the user
        getSale(saleNum);
        return true;

    } // end of confirmForm()

    // Initializing global variables
    var saleNum = 0;

    // Using an object array to store coffee prices
    var price = {
            L: { S: 2.00, M: 2.80, L: 3.60 },
            B: { S: 2.50, M: 3.00, L: 3.85 },
            D: { S: 2.75, M: 3.20, L: 4.00 }
        };

    // Empty array that will contain sales information
    var salesInfo = [];

    // End of JavaScript
```

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<form id="coffeeForm">
  <p>
    <label>Sale ID: 
         <input type="text" name="saleID" id = "saleID" value = "1000" readonly>
        </label>
    <label>Sales Count: 
         <input type="text" name="salesCount" id = "salesCount" value = "1" readonly>
        </label>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label>Coffee Type (L - Light, B - Blend, D - Dark): 
         <input type="text" name="coffeeType" id = "coffeeTypeId">
        </label>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label>Coffee Size (S - Small, M - Medium, L - Large): 
         <input type="text" name="coffeeSize" id = "coffeeSizeId">
        </label>
  </p>

  <p>
    <!-- button that will execute javascript functions when clicked by the user, then return the output -->
    <button onClick="confirmForm();return false;" class="button button1">Calculate</button>
  </p>
  <!--<div id="resultsDiv"  style="display:none;">-->
  <p>
    <label>Subtotal: 
         <input type="text" name="subtotal" id="subtotal" style = "background-color: #FFFFC2;" readonly>
        </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Sales Tax: 
         <input type="text" name="salesTax" id="salesTax" style = "background-color: #FFFFC2;" readonly>
        </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Total: 
         <input type="text" name="total" id="total" style = "background-color: #F3E5AB;" readonly>
        </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <!-- Somehow increment saleNum and saleID here after the form resets-->
    <button onClick="resetForm();" class="button button1">New Sale</button>
    <button onClick="previousSale();return false;" class="button button1">Previous Sale</button>
    <button onClick="nextSale();return false;" class="button button1">Next Sale</button>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="button button1">
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array of objects and use a counter for the inserted sales.

```js
'use strict';

function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('resultsDiv').style.display = "block";
}

function resetForm() {
    document.getElementById("coffeeForm").reset();
}

function newSale() {
    saleNum = salesInfo.length ;
    document.getElementById("coffeeForm").reset();
    document.getElementById("saleID").value = 1000 + saleNum;
    document.getElementById("salesCount").value = saleNum;
    console.log(salesInfo);
}

function getSale(saleNumber) {
    Object.keys(salesInfo[saleNum]).forEach(function (key) {
        document.getElementById(key).value = salesInfo[saleNum][key];
    });
}

function previousSale() {
    if (saleNum > 0) {
        saleNum--;
    }
    getSale(saleNum);
}

function nextSale() {
    if (saleNum < salesInfo.length - 1) {
        saleNum++;
    }
    getSale(saleNum);
}

function confirmForm() {
    var coffeeType = document.getElementById('coffeeType').value.toUpperCase(),
        coffeeSize = document.getElementById('coffeeSize').value.toUpperCase(),
        saleID = document.getElementById('saleID').value;

    if (!price[coffeeType]) {
        alert("Error: Please enter a valid coffee type (L - Light, B - Blend, D - Dark)!");
        return false;
    }

    if (!price[coffeeType][coffeeSize]) {
        alert("Error: Please enter a valid coffee size (S - Small, M - Medium, L - Large).");
        return false;
    }

    var subtotal = price[coffeeType][coffeeSize];
    var salesTax = subtotal * 0.06;
    var total = subtotal + salesTax;
    salesInfo[saleNum] = salesInfo[saleNum] || {};
    salesInfo[saleNum].saleID = saleID;
    salesInfo[saleNum].coffeeType = coffeeType;
    salesInfo[saleNum].coffeeSize = coffeeSize;
    salesInfo[saleNum].subtotal = subtotal.toFixed(2);
    salesInfo[saleNum].salesTax = salesTax.toFixed(2);
    salesInfo[saleNum].total = total.toFixed(2);
    getSale(saleNum);
    return true;
}

var saleNum = 0,
    price = {
        L: { S: 2.00, M: 2.80, L: 3.60 },
        B: { S: 2.50, M: 3.00, L: 3.85 },
        D: { S: 2.75, M: 3.20, L: 4.00 }
    },
    salesInfo = [];
```

```html
<form id="coffeeForm" onsubmit="return false;">
<p><label>Sale ID: <input type="text" name="saleID" id="saleID" value="1000" disabled></label><label>Sales Count: <input type="text" name="salesCount" id="salesCount" value="0" disabled></label></p>
<p><label>Coffee Type (L - Light, B - Blend, D - Dark): <input type="text" name="coffeeType" id="coffeeType"></label></p>
<p><label>Coffee Size (S - Small, M - Medium, L - Large): <input type="text" name="coffeeSize" id="coffeeSize"></label></p>
<p><button onClick="confirmForm();return false;" class="button button1">Calculate</button></p>
<p><label>Subtotal: <input type="text" name="subtotal" id="subtotal" style="background-color: #FFFFC2;" readonly></label></p>
<p><label>Sales Tax: <input type="text" name="salesTax" id="salesTax" style="background-color: #FFFFC2;" readonly></label></p>
<p><label>Total: <input type="text" name="total" id="total" style="background-color: #F3E5AB;" readonly></label></p>
<p><button onClick="newSale();" class="button button1">New Sale</button><button onClick="previousSale();return false;" class="button button1">Previous Sale</button><button onClick="nextSale();return false;" class="button button1">Next Sale</button><input type="reset" value="Reset" class="button button1"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: basically, i use the array for the sales as storage and check the length for increasing old sales. in the console, you get the array and the objects inside, when pressing `new Sale`. this use of objects is more convenient, than using arrays whith indices for differet types of data inside an array, as you had before. i changed as well the select case structure to an object and changed the test for the price and exit early if no price is found. i suggest to use a pulldown or some radio input elements.

Comment: it assigns `salesInfo[saleNum]` to `salesInfo[saleNum]`, if exist, bcause the it is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), or an empry object, if there is no truty value. It's a kind of default value assigned to `salesInfo[saleNum]`.